# Primefaces Panels inside OrderList

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, panel

I'd like to implement reordering of list elements using p:orderList and p:panel components. Initially there was a POJOs in list, but problem occurs even with a list of strings.

There is my bean:

```
public class BackingBean {

    private List<String> list;

    public void addDate() {
        list.add(new Date().toString());
    }    

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

My page source:

```
<p:orderList id="videos" value="#{bean.list}" var="date" itemValue="#{date}"
    controlsLocation="none">
    <p:column >
        <p:panel header="#{date}" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">
            FC Barcelona is one of only three clubs...
        </p:panel>
    </p:column>
</p:orderList>
```

The problem is that every time I toggle one of the panels, all panels are minimized and maximized a few times, i.e. if there are three elements in the list, than all panels will be maximized/minimized three times. Am I wrong?

Comment: Are multiple panels with widgetVar supported inside orderedList? It seems that the javascript variable "panel" is used for all panels inside your list. You could check it out in firebug.

Comment: I think @djmj is right. Why do you specify `widgetVar` attribute. Do you use it somewhere in javascript?

Comment: This happens even without `widgetWar`. 
I've got an answer on the primefaces forum "The problem is that all panels in the list get the same id so the toggling toggles all panels". But I don't know what should I use instead of panels

Answer (score 2):

Well, depends if you really need the reordering functionality. If you can afford to go without it, I would try ui:repeat instead of p:orderList. It generates original id for every div so you will be able to toggle just one panel at the time. Hope it helps

**EDIT:**
I made a custom "toggler" so you can toggle your panels even in p:orderList separately.

```
        <p:orderList id="videos" value="#{yourBean.list}" var="dataItem" itemValue="#{dataItem}"
                     controlsLocation="none">
            <p:column>
                <p:panel id="togglePanel">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{dataItem}" />
                            <p:commandButton value="+" onclick="showToggle(this)" style="float: right;"/>
                            <p:commandButton value="-" onclick="hideToggle(this)" style="float: right;"/>
                            <div style="clear: both"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    <div>
                        FC Barcelona is one of only three clubs...
                    </div>
                </p:panel>
            </p:column>
        </p:orderList>
```

And the simple script :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function hideToggle(param) {  
    jQuery(param).closest("div").next().slideUp('slow',null);     
}  
function showToggle(param) {  
    jQuery(param).closest("div").next().slideDown('slow',null);     
}

</script>
```

Maybe there is a nicer solution but I believe you get the point. Hope it helped.